# Jtwig if expression fails: Unable to find implementation for operator !=

Tags: java, spring, jtwig

I wrote if expression, according documentation I found. Here is what I tried:

```
{% if idol_response.didYouMean != "" %}
    <p>aaaaaaa</p>
{% endif %}
```

also:

```
{% if (idol_response.didYouMean != "") %}
    <p>aaaaaaa</p>
{% endif %}
```

and:

```
{% if (not idol_response.didYouMean == "") %}
    <p>aaaaaaa</p>
{% endif %}
```

Any of the above do not work, which kind of makes me nervous ;-)
The first two gives:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.lyncode.jtwig.exception.CompileException: Unable to find implementation for operator !=
```

I do not comment the third expression, because I admit it is not correct syntax. First two should be fine acording to all sources.
didYouMean is a field of idol_response object and I need to check if it is empty or not.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is `didYouMean`'s type?

Comment: didYouMean is a field of idol_response.

Comment: ... Yes, I can see that. That does not describe its *type*.

Comment: Mainly this is a java List of objects called responses from idol server. didYouMean is a field of the response.

Comment: ... *TYPE*. You know how values in Java have a type, like "String" etc.?

Comment: As I wrote above. Again: List<IdolResponse>

Comment: ... Again: What is `didYouMean`'s type? It's not a `List<IdolResponse>`. `didYouMean` is a property of an `IdolResponse`. WHAT IS THE TYPE OF THAT PROPERTY? Holy crap.

Comment: Its a custom object. Its type is IdolResponse. didYouMean is a String. I think we do not understand each other. Thank you for trying help, and I am very sorry I cant answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The first and second expressions was a known bug, which was fixed in 3.0.1, check https://github.com/lyncode/jtwig/pull/179.

The third expression is an operation precedence issue. Try the following:

```
{% if (not (idol_response.didYouMean == "")) %}
<p>aaaaaaa</p>
{% endif %}
```